# typescript paths with vscode resolve wrong on ctrl click

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a library whose source code I am modifying, I downloaded the source code for it and wanted to point vscode, typescript & webpack towards that file.

In webpack I aliased the library successfully, but vsc doesn't seem to want to use the `files` property of `tsconfig.json` over the `node_modules`.

When ctrl clicking an import like

```js
import {myModule} from "myModule/breh"
```

with a `tsconfig` like this

```json
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "myModule/*": ["myModule/src/*"]
}
```

it doesn't go to the correct path, it always goes to `node_modules`.

The location of the library is under `src/myModule/src`.

Answer (score 0):

of course. The recommended baseUrl is node_modules. So errthing should le relative to it which means the correct path you need to add in paths is

```
"baseUrl":"./node_modules",
"paths": {
    "exact name as in the import": ["../dir/file.d.ts"]

}
```

As the base is node modules you need to tell it to out at its father dir

Comment: It unfortunately still goes to `node_modules` after you ctrl click on the imported property